# Install app on computer with no internet

Tags: windows-10

I have two computers:

- Surface pro running windows 10 for recreational use (has internet)
- Desktop running windows 10 for high performance tasks like video editing (no internet to minimize ad/bloat/malware)

I know what you are thinking, and yes, the above setup is a very extreme solution, but this is a personal principle of mine and I'd like to adhere to it unless it's a matter of life or death.

The trouble is I need to install an app on my desktop but that obviously is not so straight-forward given I stubbornly deny it internet access.

What I tried: I downloaded the app from the microsoft store then copied and pasted everything that came with the download onto my desktop. However the executable did not run and threw no error message.

I concede that my needs are deep and go beyond the needs of ordinary users, but given that this is "super" user SE, maybe I can keep some hope afloat. Theoretically, it's all just 1's and 0's, I'd be surprised if my task truly impossible.

### Question

If you don't mind humoring my one-device-connected-to-the-internet-setup, is there some half-decent method for downloading microsofts apps on one device and installing them on another?

**Note:** The question is posed for the general case, but for reference the app in question for my case is: https://gopro.com/help/articles/block/GoPro-Max-Exporter. (no standalone installer, customer support unable to help)

Comment: This seems to be a rather convoluted process http://woshub.com/how-to-download-appx-installation-file-for-any-windows-store-app/

Comment: Connect to internet, download app, then disconnect.